# Login issue on Mac given to me

Tags: mac, login

I was given a Mac computer that belonged to a local school. Was told that the school info had been removed. When I boot up, I receive a "login page" asking for username and password. I do not know the proper info used on this computer in the past, have tried no info, just hitting return, as well as normal basic words such as admin, etc. to no avail. Can't get any further as nothing else comes up when turning on the computer. Being a PC user for years, I don't really know much about Mac computers, I use one at work but all the setup stuff is already in place. Any way around this??? I have emailed the gentleman who gave me the computer but have yet to hear back from him on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

if you have the OSX install disc, you can change the password using this.  [This article from apple support will help.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1274) Good luck, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the MacOS X installation disk with the system, you can reset the password in the following way (or something linke that, I am writing from memory):

Enter the CD. While starting the system, press the C key until the Apple logo appears (to start from the CD). At some point in the installation process, a menu bar appears and there will be a item to reset the admin password.